# Updated Laptop From Windows 8.1 to 10. Mouse now functionally disappears after logging in

Tags: mouse, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I've just updated my laptop to Windows 10. Everything seems fine: I can type and move my mouse up until I enter my password to log into the laptop. From there the mouse not just "disappears" but is functionally not there.

Clicking does nothing, even when I move the trackpad so that it should be resting on something like the bottom right button to get to the desktop and minimise everything.

I have tried following the instructions on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sA_oKgGynkI suggested in another thread, to not hide mouse when typing. It was tricky to execute with no mouse, when the video uses a mouse to do it lol. However, I followed it and it didn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem few days ago. I searched everywhere and finally found a topic where it says "windows 10 hybrid startup system dont load all driver" . I disabled this option and it worked for me. Not sure about whether it will work for you or not. You have to go into "power option" to fix it. Here is a [YouTube video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Gi1LIeB5ys) that shows you how to do it :